# Declaring variable length strings in c - apparently dynamic?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand something basic about how 'strings' are defined in c.

```
char s[2];
scanf("%s", s);
printf("%s", s);
printf("sizeof s %d", sizeof(s));
```

I'm not a c programmer. I'm aware that there are problems with using scanf to get user input and that I'm not even checking its return value etc. This is just to understand something basic about declaring strings.

Given the above code what it does if I enter say 'helloworld' is print 'helloworld'. Good. But I thought by saying char s[2] I was saying something like 's is an array of length two where each element is of type char'.

Thus I was expecting to see 'he' printed. Not 'helloworld'. Because my s array only has room for 2 chars.

The sizeof still returns 2. But it looks like my array has grown to the size of the user input.

What is happening?

Comment: It hasn't grown. You've allocated 2 chars for `s` and that's how much memory is set aside on the stack for it. However, `scanf()` just receives a pointer to the memory. It has no way of knowing how much memory is allocated, so it just reads and stores, writing to memory that is probably set side for something else, until it's done. It's up to you to do the memory management part. These kinds of bugs are the source of many "what the...?" debugging moments because it typically looks like something *else* is broken.

Comment: Why doesn't he have &s in his scanf?

Comment: You are overwriting the bounds of your array, thus inducing undefined behavior. You're correct that your array only has 2 `char`s. You're just getting lucky that writing beyond 2 `char`s isn't wrecking something else. You may not be so lucky on another machine or with different compiler options. Furthermore, `c` strings are NULL (`\0`) terminated, so you'll need an extra character in the array for that. "helloworld" is 10 `char`s long, meaning you'll need a `char` array 11 `char`s long to properly store it.

Comment: No, the array hasn't grown. By entering a long text you've overwritten part of the stack (or whatever memory the array was allocated in) outside the array. When that happens with stack memory, it usually leads to crashes or execution of unwanted code, especially when the code is part of a remotely accessible service.

Comment: You've expose the very flaw in `scanf` which is that it's not memory safe. If you used `fgets` here, you'd get `h` as your return (don't forget the null terminator).

Comment: @OmidCompSCI because when `s` is used in this context, it decays to a pointer to the first element in the array.

Comment: @yano technically s is s = &char[0]?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: Unless it's the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  Note that `&s` and `s` yield the same address value, but the *types* of the expressions are different - `char (*)[2]` vs `char *`.  `scanf` expects a `char *` for the `%s` specifier, so the argument should be `s`.

Comment: You are experiencing a **buffer overflow**, means that you are writing onto memory you didn't allocate/reserve. Standard says it is undefined behavior. Always use functions that bounds the memory they write in some way.

Comment: @EliSadoff: Just because it is not used correctly does not make `scanf` "inherently unsafe". OP could easily have limited the length of the input to a safe range or use `scanf_s` if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- C does not do any bounds checking on array accesses;
- Under most circumstances, an *expression* of array type will be converted to an expression of pointer type, and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  This includes array expressions passed as arguments to functions.

The `%s` conversion specification tells `printf` to print the *sequence* of characters starting at the specified address until it sees the 0 terminator at the end of the string.  Similarly, it tells `scanf` to store a sequence of characters starting at the specified address until it sees a whitespace character or EOF.

When you pass the *expression* `s` as an argument to `scanf` or `printf`, the expression is converted from type "2-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array (it's equivalent to passing the expression `&s[0]`).

All `scanf` receives is a pointer value - it has no idea how big the array starting at that address is.  So it doesn't know that `s` is only large enough to contain two characters.  Instead, it happily writes those extra characters past the end of the array.  Similarly, `printf` doesn't know that the array is only 2 characters wide - it just keeps printing until it sees that 0 terminator.

You can specify a *field width* as part of the conversion:

```
scanf( "%1s", s );
```

This will read *at most* 1 character from standard input and store it to `s`.  Remember that a *string* is a sequence of characters followed by a 0 terminator, so to store an N-character string, you need to set aside an N+1-element array to store it.

Comment: Nice answer.  Detail: "C does not do any bounds checking on array accesses;" --> It is simply UB,  A compiler _could_ do bounds checking.  Bounds checking is certainly not specified C behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This shows the perfect reason as to why `scanf` is so dangerous. You've overwritten other memory that was not intended for this. A much safer way to read constant length strings is to do something like this

```
char a[2];
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
printf("%s\n", a);
```

If you did this and you typed `helloworld` you would only get `h` to stdout (because strings have `sizeof(a) - 1` characters due to the null terminator. This means the array `a` is actually `{'h', '\0'}`). `fgets` is a lot safer for reading constantly sized strings than `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has actually answered this question yet. There are two problems here...

First, the array "s" is only 2 bytes long, so *scanf* of any string more than 1 character will generate undesired results.

```
char s[255]; // was char s[2];
```

Also, as mentioned before, *scanf* is a horrible way to input strings. Use *fgets* instead.

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin); // was scanf("%s", s);
```

Second, you cannot use *sizeof* to get the length of a string. It will return you the length of the array that contains the string (not what you want, trust me). Instead, use *strlen*.

```
printf("strlen s %d", strlen(s)); // was printf("sizeof s %d", sizeof(s));
```

Comment: Detail: Code can use `sizeof` to get the size of a _string_.  `strlen(p)` uses the _pointer_ `p`, which points to a _string_ and returns the length of the string.  In C, a _string_ is an array.