# Why does the malloc work without correct number of bytes allocated?

Tags: c, string, malloc, c-strings

I have a simple question which I don't seem to be able to find an answer to anywhere.

**Why does this code compile and work when i allocated enough memory for just two characters, "he", "hellos" shouldnt be able to fit?**

It prints out correct length, which is 6.

The free gives no error.

```
char* testF() {
    char *arr = (char*)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(arr, "hellos");
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    char *arr = testF();
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
    printf("Length = %d", strlen(arr));
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. This is UB.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40271508/5021321).

Comment: What does UB mean?

Comment: You're lucky (or unlucky if in some scenario you think that your code is bug-free). In many cases a program would crash / have a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Lurr Undefined behaviour

Comment: PS -You do not need the cast - it is bad - please google it

Comment: @EdHeal What case?

Comment: I made a typo - cast

Comment: Ah. Yeah, you needn't case to `(char *)`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to `1`; there's never any need for `* sizeof(char)`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252033/in-c-why-is-sizeofchar-1-when-a-is-an-int

Comment: _"hellos" shouldnt be able to fit?_  What do you think should have happened?

Comment: @chux well, just the onese that were allocated, in this case maybe just the he, without null terminator, which is bad.

Comment: Reasonable to think that only first 1 or 2 characters `"hello"` would be copied to `ar` which has allocated memory for 2 bytes .  In order to archive that, the executable code of `strcpy()` would need to test if the copying exceed the size.  That test takes time and a mechanism to save/denote the size (memory overhead).  This is why C is fast.  It trusts the programmer did not need the test so less code, less overhead --> higher performance.  Just don't fall off the tight-rope - there is no net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen, if there is free memory after the area which was allocated by malloc.

But of course you must count on it. Trust only what you allocate.

Actually this is a source for nasty bugs, because some bad code like mallocing insufficient memory or using deallocated memory can work. And then one day you make a small change that affects the memory scheme, or update a compiler version, and things start to crash...

Comment: So basically, IF I'm unlucky in a bigger program that I write stuff on the memory where the rest, "llos" of "hellos" is saved, I would get a crash when accessing it? Or bad values? @designerman

Comment: If you are unlucky enough, there won't be any crash for a time, and after you change something, there will be...

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this code compile and work when i allocated enough memory for just two characters, "he", "hellos" shouldnt be able to fit?

It's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `strcpy()` call overflows the buffer.

The C standard doesn't require an implementation to give error or warnings on *undefined* behaviours. So, you can't expect anything to save you; you are on your own.

Comment: Should I change the malloc to
char **arr = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
or
char **arr = (char*)malloc(7*sizeof(char));
to properly store it?

Comment: It must be `7` bytes, including the null byte termination. So, the latter. You should also check the return value of `malloc()` to see if it's failed: `if (arr == NULL) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`.

Comment: @Lurr `*arr = malloc(7 * sizeof(*arr));` would now probably be the best thing to use. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you get no error is because the amount of data you copy can still fit within the memory page. If you were to, by chance copy data that resulted in a page overflow, you'd get a SIGSEGV (segmentation) error.

In conclusion, this is undefined behaviour.